# How to configure spring security 3.2 to use dao authentication and custom authentication filter using java config

Tags: java, spring-security, java-ee-7, spring-java-config

I have googled spring security examples using dao authentication and custom authentication filter, but which are I found, all the examples are using xml file configuration,

My question is how to configure custom filter i.e. **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter**

my xml based securityConfig file looks like:

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />        
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth/login.html" access="permitAll" />     
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth/logout.html" access="permitAll" />        
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth/accessDenied.html" access="permitAll" />      
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />


    <access-denied-handler error-page="/auth/accessDenied.html"/>

    <form-login login-page='/auth/login.html' 
        default-target-url="/"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/auth/loginfailed.html" />

    <logout success-handler-ref="myLogoutSuccessHandler"
            invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />

    <remember-me key="uniqueAndSecret" token-validity-seconds="86400" />

     <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" 
            session-authentication-error-url="/auth/loginfailed.html"> 
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" 
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" 
                expired-url="/auth/login.html" 
                session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>
    </session-management>

</http>

<beans:bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
    class="com.asn.handler.AsnUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

<beans:bean id="myLogoutSuccessHandler" 
    class="com.asn.handler.AsnLogoutSuccessHandler" />

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.asn.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"/>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">      
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"> 
        <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>                      
    </authentication-provider>
    <!-- <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user1" password="user1Pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="admin1" password="admin1Pass" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider> -->
</authentication-manager>

<!-- For hashing and salting user passwords -->
<beans:bean id="encoder" 
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

I want to convert the configuration's into **Java configuration** based..
i have tried like this which is doesn't work:

**SecurityConfig class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder encoder;

    /*@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)throws Exception {
        logger.info("configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) invoked..");
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);       
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**","/assets/**","/files/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth","/").permitAll()                           

                .anyRequest().authenticated() //every request requires the user to be authenticated
                .and()
            .formLogin() //form based authentication is supported
                .loginPage("/auth/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();

        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/auth/accessDenied");

        http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().migrateSession()
            .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(concunSessContAuthStr());
    }

    @Bean(name="sessionRegistry")
    public SessionRegistryImpl sessionRegistryBean(){
        logger.info("sessionRegistryBean() invoked..");
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authFilter() throws Exception{
        logger.info("authFilter() invoked.."); 
        CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter upaf = new CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        upaf.setAuthenticationManager(".."); //here, how to set AuthenticationManager ??
        upaf.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(concunSessContAuthStr());
        return upaf;
    }


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationManagerBean() {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider dap = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        dap.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        dap.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
        return dap;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concunSessContAuthStr(){
        logger.info("concunSessContAuthStr() invoked.."); 
        ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy cscas= new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistryBean());
        cscas.setMaximumSessions(2);
        cscas.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(true);
        return cscas;
    }

}
```

Any Suggestions how to configure?

Thank You!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use a customized class replacing the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter do the following:

- create a new class `FormLoginConfigurer` with the following content (the original `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.FormLoginConfigurer` is unfortunately final and cannot be extended), notice the call to `super(new CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter(),null)`:

  ```
  package demo;

  import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.HttpSecurityBuilder;
  import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer;
  import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
  import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter;
  import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
  import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

  public class FormLoginConfigurer<H extends HttpSecurityBuilder<H>> extends AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer<H,FormLoginConfigurer<H>,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter> {

  public FormLoginConfigurer() {
      super(new CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter(),null);
      usernameParameter("username");
      passwordParameter("password");
  }

  public FormLoginConfigurer<H> loginPage(String loginPage) {
      return super.loginPage(loginPage);
  }

  public FormLoginConfigurer<H> usernameParameter(String usernameParameter) {
      getAuthenticationFilter().setUsernameParameter(usernameParameter);
      return this;
  }

  public FormLoginConfigurer<H> passwordParameter(String passwordParameter) {
      getAuthenticationFilter().setPasswordParameter(passwordParameter);
      return this;
  }

  @Override
  public void init(H http) throws Exception {
      super.init(http);
      initDefaultLoginFilter(http);
  }

  @Override
  protected RequestMatcher createLoginProcessingUrlMatcher(
          String loginProcessingUrl) {
      return new AntPathRequestMatcher(loginProcessingUrl, "POST");
  }

  private String getUsernameParameter() {
      return getAuthenticationFilter().getUsernameParameter();
  }

  private String getPasswordParameter() {
      return getAuthenticationFilter().getPasswordParameter();
  }

  private void initDefaultLoginFilter(H http) {
      DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter loginPageGeneratingFilter = http.getSharedObject(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.class);
      if(loginPageGeneratingFilter != null && !isCustomLoginPage()) {
          loginPageGeneratingFilter.setFormLoginEnabled(true);
          loginPageGeneratingFilter.setUsernameParameter(getUsernameParameter());
          loginPageGeneratingFilter.setPasswordParameter(getPasswordParameter());
          loginPageGeneratingFilter.setLoginPageUrl(getLoginPage());
          loginPageGeneratingFilter.setFailureUrl(getFailureUrl());
          loginPageGeneratingFilter.setAuthenticationUrl(getLoginProcessingUrl());
      }
  }
  ```

  }
- remove the `formLogin()` call from your `configure(HttpSecurity)` method and use the following initialization instead:

  ```
   FormLoginConfigurer formLogin = new FormLoginConfigurer();
   http.apply(formLogin);
   formLogin.loginPage("/auth/login")
           .permitAll();
  ```
- the authentication manager will be provided to your instance automatically
- you can customize the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` used in your class by calls to `http.sessionManagement()`, or you can add logic to your new `FormLoginConfigurer` which updates whatever you need

Another option is to register your `CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` filter as an additional filter:

- in the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method call:

  ```
   http.addFilter(authFilter());
  ```
- make sure to configure all options of the filter manually
- beware that system will also add another instance of the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter after yours

In order to add a custom `AuthenticationProvider`:

- override method `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` and add the provider:

  ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationManagerBean());
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You are close !

```
upaf.setAuthenticationManager(".."); //here, how to set AuthenticationManager ??
```

The answer is :

```
upaf.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
```

Also, add your Custom like this :

```
http
.addFilterBefore(authFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```